# Rails 4 resource customization issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a tags resource:

```
resources :tags, only: [:index, :show, :update, :destroy]
```

And I'm trying to copy the functionality of the `tags/tag` partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'tags/tag', collection: tags %> ## <~ my copy ##
<%= render partial: 'collections/collection', collection: collections %>
<%= render partial: 'saved_searches/saved_search', collection: saved_searches %>
<%= render partial: 'tags/tag', collection: tags %>
<%= render feeds %>
```

Here is the `_tag.html.erb` partial:

```
<% hide_drawer = (session[:view_mode] == 'view_unread' && tag.unread_count == 0 && !tag.user_feeds.any?) ? true : false %>
<li data-tag-id="<%= tag.id %>" data-feed-id="tag-<%= tag.id %>" class="<%= selected("tag_#{tag.id}") %>">
  <%= link_to tag_path(tag.id), remote: true, class: 'feed-link tag-link', data: { behavior: 'selectable reset_entry_position show_entries open_item feed_link', mark_read: {type: 'tag', data: tag.id, message: "Mark #{tag.name} as read?"}.to_json } do %>
    <span class="favicon-wrap">
      <span class="favicon favicon-tag"></span>
    </span>
    <%= content_tag :span, tag.unread_count, class: 'count' + hide_count(tag.unread_count) %>
    <% unless hide_drawer %>
      <%= render partial: 'tags/tag_visibility', locals: {user: @user, tag: tag} %>
    <% end %>
    <%= tag.name %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="drawer <%= hide_drawer ? ' hide' : '' %>" data-hidden="<%= drawer_visible?(tag.id) ? 'false' : 'true' %>" style="<%= drawer_visible?(tag.id) ? '' : 'height: 0;' %>">
    <ul>
      <%= render tag.user_feeds %>
    </ul>
    <i class="drawer-arrow"></i>
  </div>
</li>
```

And here is the show method:

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    update_selected_feed!("tag", params[:id])

    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @feed_ids = Tagging.where(tag_id: @tag, user_id: @user).pluck(:feed_id)

    feeds_response

    @append = !params[:page].nil?

    @type = 'tag'
    @data = params[:id]

    @collection_title = @tag.name
    @collection_favicon = 'favicon-tag'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render partial: 'shared/entries' }
    end
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is reuse the same partial and only output the tag named "Mailbox". Would I need to add some logic to the method to have the partial show only the tag named "Mailbox"?  How would I tell the partial to display only a single "Mailbox" tag? Any suggestions or help would be appreciated I'm a new Rails developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.

Pass local

```
<%= render partial: 'tags/tag', locals: {tag: tags.find{|t| t.name == "Mailbox"}}%>
```

Pass an array with just just one tag

```
<%= render partial: 'tags/tag', collection: tags.collect{|t| t.name == "Mailbox"} %>
```

Comment: Give `undefined method 'unread_count' for true:TrueClass`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Using the locals version worked, but the collection one did not. Also added the reject method to the normals tags: `tags.reject { |t| t.name == "Mailbox" }`